# Policy on appropriating answer parts, and timing

Tags: discussion

I have a question about this recent [AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833070/how-would-i-pass-the-output-of-one-command-to-multiple-commands). My answer (let's call it A2) was not accepted, in favour of another one (A1). I don't mind this that much, but I would like to understand if the situation is all kosher, and if there is anything I can do differently in the future. Here are some facts:

- My answer A2 was first by more than 3 minutes.
- In the original form (rev 1), A2 succinctly answers the OP (IMO). The 2 subsequent revisions only add some extra information.
- The answer A1 contains false information in revs 1&2 (about the ordering of the output). I made a comment about this issue, which was subsequently incorporated in A1 rev 3.
- A1 rev 4 copies a part of A2, that addresses the printing of the last word, which was a small part of OP.
- A1 rev 5 copies from A2 the clean-looking example code `tee >(wc -l) >(wc -w) >(wc -c)`.

Are there any rules that might apply to this situation? For example, does the timing (being first) and content of A2 rev 1 matter at all? Is this all at the OP author's discretion? Also, is it ok for A1 to appropriate parts of A2? Is there anything I should do differently in such a situation?

Comment: Up to OP what they accept, nothing anyone else can do. I don't see how that answer took anything from yours. Sure it is crap to not get accepted but the other answer is more detailed and longer and the the OP deemed it better. This happens, it is not first come first served, move on, don't let it get to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid, but You can't do anything in these situation. It's all OP author's discretion. I think what happened is, OP asked the question and left the site. Later when he visited again, found two answers and accepted the one he/she thought most useful.